# Why is this simple Django view/urlpattern nonfunctional?

Tags: django, django-views

Both files are in the directory "polls".

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/$', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I had thought that this would handle the url, call the "poll" function, and make the page http://localhost:8000/poll display the appropriate message.  No matter what, all I get is a 404 error and Django reporting back that it only attempted to try the url pattern "^admin/" but the current url did not match this.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `polls.urls` in the **project**'s `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^poll/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: I did so and also added in "from django.contrib import admin" to be safe, but nothing changed.

Comment: In which file you did it? In the `projectname/urls.py`?

Comment: Yeah; I've updated the contents of the two files in my post in case what I attempted wasn't what you'd intended to suggest.

Comment: You did it in the wrong file. You should add this include to the `projectname/urls.py` instead of `polls/urls.py`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to clarify that.  Should anything be in the "polls/urls.py" instead of (or in addition to) the projectname one? If so, what differentiates between what should go in polls/urls.py and projectname/urls.py?

Comment: `polls/urls.py` should contain urls for the `polls` app. In your case it is just a single line with `views.poll` view.  `projectname/urls.py` is a "root" list of all site's urls. Some urls can be defined here (for example `home`) but the usual way is to aggregate urls from different apps using the `include()` function.

Comment: Read this chapter of the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reach it at `/poll`, while your urlconf specifies `r'^$'`, which is the equivalent of root url, i.e. `/`. Either change your urlconf to `r'^poll/$'` or try opening `http://localhost:8000/`.

So your `urls.py` should look something like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.views import index

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/$', index),
    url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Changed this, still doesn't work.  Thank you, though.

Comment: Changed to what exactly?

Comment: The urlconf you suggested; I've edited the updated urls.py into my original post.

Comment: As far as I can see, you have implemented suggestions from both of the answers. I'll update my answer to be more clear what I meant.